# How to avoid conflicts in grammar

Tags: javascript, parser-generator, jison

I have a grammar file — https://github.com/itrelease/fubar-script/blob/jsast/src/grammar.js but I get [conflicts](https://gist.github.com/2597616) and I don't really know how to solve this. If someone could explain me it would be helpful.

This rules produce [conflicts](https://gist.github.com/2597616):

```
ParamVar: [
  ['Identifier', '$$ = $Identifier;'],
  ['THIS', '$$ = new yy.ThisExpression();']
],

PrimaryExpression: [
  ['THIS', '$$ = new yy.ThisExpression();'],
  ['Literal', '$$ = $Literal;'],
  ['ArrayLiteral', '$$ = $ArrayLiteral;'],
  ['Identifier', '$$ = $Identifier;'],
  ['ObjectLiteral', '$$ = $ObjectLiteral;'],
  ['( Expression )', '$$ = $Expression;']
],
```

Comment: Please post the necessary parts of your grammar, and the errors, here on SO.

Comment: Added to question rules that causes the conflicts.

Comment: Anton, it will help other people to help you if you provide the steps that you take to reproduce the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current grammar does not have a `PrimaryExpressionNoBrace`, but I presume that the problem occurred with [this](https://github.com/itrelease/fubar-script/blob/e557c3f24237f72d7ff053ea32fee2169ed55d40/src/grammar.js) older version of the grammar.

The conflict is caused by this production:

```
MemberExpression: [
      ['PrimaryExpression', '$$ = $PrimaryExpression;'],
      ['ArrowFunctionExpression', '$$ = $ArrowFunctionExpression'],
      ...
```

where

- a `PrimaryExpression` derives to a `PrimaryExpressionNoBrace` which has `'( Expression )'`
- Expression again derives to `PrimaryExpressionNoBrace` which has `IDENTIFIER` or `THIS` alternatives
- an `ArrowFunctionExpression` has `'( FormalParameterList ) => Block'`
- `FormalParameterList` has `IDENTIFIER` or `THIS` alternatives, too.

Thus the input of a left parenthesis, followed by an `IDENTIFIER` or `THIS` takes us into an LR-state that cannot decide between reducing to `PrimaryExpressionNoBrace` or to `FormalParameterList`, i.e. it has reduce-reduce conflicts on common legal followers (e.g. a right parenthesis). A single token lookahead is not suffient here, and there is no support for more.

Comment: Doesn't this page https://github.com/zaach/jison/wiki/Deviations-From-Flex-Bison explains that we can use lookahead ?

Comment: @TrexXx, this is about lexer lookahead, in terms of characters. When I said lookahead above, that was parser level lookahead, in terms of tokens.

Comment: Ok, so this is impossible to use parser level lookahead with Jison ? Is there a way to avoir conflicts in a grammar without using lookahead  ?

Comment: @TrexXx, there is a lookahead of one token, which is not enough in this case, i.e. a decision is necessary when there are still multiple possibilities. For solving this one, it might be possible (though not nice) to combine `)=>` into a single token. Note that this might require extra handling of embedded whitespace in the lexer. Otherwise, the grammar must be rewritten in a way that does not ask for decisions before enough information is available, under the constraints imposed by the parsing algorithm.

Comment: What you could do is give up `ParamVar` and use `Expr` instead, this would avoid having to decide early. It does however allow unwanted syntax, which would then have to be blocked after parsing.